# composite video comes back on with wrong resolution after 'tvservice --off' on model B with BCM2835

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-buster, composite-video

I am running buster on a model B rev.2 serving as a text-only signage display with a cheap 800x480 LCD car monitor attached to the composite video output (sdtv).
The settings in /boot/config.txt are:

```
disable_overscan=1
framebuffer_width=800
framebuffer_height=480
sdtv_mode=2
sdtv_aspect=3
```

The pi boots up with its text console filling the screen properly.
I get 26 lines of text on the display starting in the upper left corner and about half a line of black pixels on the top and at the bottom.

The problem comes up when I try to switch the display back on after having it blanked with

```
tvservice --off      # vcgencmd display_power 0  doesn't work on BCM2835
```

I use the following code to get it back on

```
  fbset --all -g 800 480 800 480 32 2>/dev/null # create frame buffer, ignore ioctl error
  tvservice --sdtvon="PAL 16:9"      >/dev/null # enable FBAS output
  fbset -accel true                             # change hardware text acceleration
  fbset -accel false                            #  to get framebuffer working again
```

This brings on the display, but now the 26 lines have a smaller font and there is a black border at the top and at the bottom with the height of app. 2 lines and the 1st column of text is not visible anymore.

I did try with different frame buffer sizes but did not succeed to get back the display like it comes up at booting.
E.g. I tried

```
fbset --all -g 656 416 656 416 32
```

which are the values that 'fbset -s' shows me, but it has no effect on the display at all.

What makes the display come back on so differently, and how can I possibly get it corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
I found that setting sdtv modes in config.txt

```
sdtv_mode=2
sdtv_aspect=3
```

had no effect, whereas setting it with the tvservice command did do the changes.
Thus, after booting

```
#tvservice -s 
state 0x40000 [NTSC 4:3], 720x480 @ 60.00Hz, interlaced
```

always has the above defaults and I must not change it to keep my display as it was.
So I changed my tvON sequence to:

```
# cat /usr/local/bin/tvON
if tvservice -s | grep -q off
then
  fbset --all -g 800 480 800 480 32 2>/dev/null # create frame buffer, ignore ioctl error
  tvservice --sdtvon="NTSC 4:3"      >/dev/null # enable FBAS output to boot default
  chvt 2                                        # change to virtual console 2
  chvt 1                                        # change back to console 1 to enable display
fi
```

and everything works as desired.